# Angularjs - unexpected order of execution

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a strange problem that only causes a problem in IE (any version) but not Chrome.

I have an array called "items" within an object called "doc" - users can edit items which actually deletes the item but adds the content back into a text box so users can add it again after making some changes.

The code for the edit function is:

```
$scope.editItem = function(index) {
    console.log($scope.doc); //debugging
    item = $scope.doc.items[index];
    $scope.content = item.data
    $scope.doc.items.splice(index,1);
};
```

Starting out with 3 items, during debugging I've noticed that the `console.log($scope.doc)` (line 2) outputs the doc with only 2 items in it. This is before the array has been spliced. I would expect it to say there are three items.

I've also checked that index is passed correctly from the view so this isn't the problem area.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you update an example in jsfiddle? It is hard to understand

Comment: Hi, I agree with  Aditya Sethi, I suspect that you are not using the splice method for what you are wanting to achieve. See [link](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/splice) for examples on splice.

Answer (score 0):

It can be that console.log prints object not immediately(possibly it saves reference and prints it a bit later).

Try to replace `console.log($scope.doc);` with `console.log($scope.doc.length);` or something like `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.doc));`